# Is there software for reading acsm files?

Tags: software-installation, compatibility, ebooks

my University Library uses bluefire reader, for allowing off site viewing of ebooks. The software produces .acsm files, and is compatible with Android, and IOS. Is there a software for Ubuntu which will let me read these acsm files?